# Kubernetes with databases - what are the options when inserting/updating?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster with Kubegress with:

- 1 primary pod for writing/selecting and 1 secondary pod just for selecting.
- 1 service for the primary pod and 1 service for the secondary pod.

How should I implement the selection of the right pod?

- in the application that connects to PostgreSQL where I should have 2 connectors: 1 for writing and 1 for selecting
- or is there some solution at the Kubernetes level so I can create a single service/load balancer?

I can't imagine any solution at the Kubernetes level.